H-NMR conjugated pi system
Given is the following conjugated molecule (see image, molecule is drawn in black) with 5 aromatic protons (labelled as A, B, C) and 4 vinylic protons (labelled as D, E, F, G). I want to predict the relative chemical shift (H-NMR) of the aromatic hydrogens A, B, C, and the relative chemical shift of the vinylic hydrogens D, E, F, G.
For this, I have included the structures of the resonance contributors of the conjugated molecule (see image).
Part 1: Aromatic protons A, B, C:
The resonance contributors show that both carbon A, and C feature a partial positive and partial negative charge (see image). Since an incomplete octet is very unstable, the negative partial charge probably contributes more to the resonance hybrid.
Does this mean that protons A, and C are more shielded (lower ppm) than proton B? And what would be the relative chemical shift of protons A and proton C, and why? I cannot find a relevant structural difference between these two (A and C).
Part 2: Vinylic protons D, E, F, G: The resonance contributors show a partial positive charge on carbon D and G, meaning that protons D and G would appear more downfield (higher ppm) compared to protons E and F. But what would be the relative chemical shift between protons D and G, and between protons E and F, and why? Would G be more deshielded (higher ppm) than D, because of its proximity to the electron-withdrawing ester moiety? Would F be more deshielded for the same reason? Or would G be more deshielded (higher ppm) than D, because the red contributors contribute more to the resonance hybrid? Or are there other factors in play?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!


These structures in the bottom are irrelevant. Structures with + are all deshielded, the closer to the carboxyl group the more.

Could you help me understand why the structures in the bottom are irrelevant? Would this mean for the vinylic protons that δG > δD>δF>δE? What about the aromatic protons? Aromatic protons A, and C are both deshielded, but which one is more deshielded and why?

Carboxyl is electron withdrawing, as simple as that. Why not get to the absurd structure with + on O to highlight it? Mesomeric effect decreases with distance: F > D >A > C, but there's also  inductive G > D > F > E.

Chemical shifts in NMR cannot be solely explained by resonance effects. You must learn more about anisotropy to understand chemical shift changes due to substitution pattern. For instance, you have given the structure methyl (2E,4E)-5-phenylpenta-2,4-dienoate molecule. Do you expect (2Z,4E)-5-phenylpenta-2,4-dienoate molecule gives the identical NMR spectrum since both molecule have ideal resonance effects? The two molecules have vastly different NMR spectra due to their anisotropy differences.
You may need to read more about basic NMR principles to predict chemical shifts from given spectrum. I'd suggest Reference 1 given below is a good starting point for a novice. For example, Ref.1 shows the anisotropy effect differences on chemical shifts on gem-, cis-, and trans-substitutions on an alkene molecule (Appendix D, Table D1; page 194). For instance, proton D on your molecule has gem-$\ce{Ph}$-substitution and cis-$\ce{CH=CH}$-substitution. Although, both substitutions can be considered as conjugated alkene systems, aromatic system has different anisotropy effect. Thus, chemical shift of D would be (considering the chemical shift of unsubstituted alkene is $\pu{5.25 ppm}$):
$$\delta \ \left(5.25+0.08(cis)+1.35(gem)\right)=\pu{6.68 ppm}$$
Similarly, proton E has gem-$\ce{CH=CH}$-substitution and cis-$\ce{Ph}$-substitution, switching the substitution pattern. Thus, the chemical shift (since the gem-substitutions is a conjugated alkene systems) would be:
$$\delta \ \left(5.25+0.37(cis)+1.26(gem)\right)=\pu{6.88 ppm}$$
But, proton F on your molecule has gem-$\ce{CH=CH}$-substitution and cis-$\ce{COOR}$- substitution. The alkene can be considered conjugated while ester function is not further conjugated. Thus, chemical shift of F would be:
$$\delta \ \left(5.25+1.15(cis)+1.26(gem)\right)=\pu{7.66 ppm}$$
However, proton G on your molecule has cis-$\ce{CH=CH}$-substitution and gem-$\ce{COOR}$- substitution. Since, the alkene substitution can still be considered conjugated while ester function is not further conjugated, the chemical shift of F would be:
$$\delta \ \left(5.25+0.08(cis)+0.84(gem)\right)=\pu{6.17 ppm}$$
You'd see the calculated chemical shifts are not the values resonance suggests. Yet, note that those calculated values are not exactly equal to actual values but they are close approximations.
References:

Robert M. Silverstein, Francis X. Webster, and David J. Kiemle, Spectrometric Identification of Organic Molecules; 7th Edition, John Wiley & Sons, Inc.: New York, NY, 2005 (ISBN: 0-471-39362-2).

